# How to recover IMAP folders from iCloud?

Tags: mail.app, icloud, recovery

I accidentally (!!) deleted a synched IMAP folder on iCloud from Mail.app. It was a large project folder with many clients in it but none of them show up in deleted messages.

This is incredibly urgent and devastating. Can anyone tell me how to perform a recovery? Initial Google searches have revealed surprisingly little on that scenario.

Comment: In ~/Library/Mail, the folder still exists even with all the subfolders. Problem is that only one subfolder holds a Info.plist and thus only that folder shows up in mail. All other folders a empty.

Comment: If the folders are empty, the content is gone. Did you check the Trash on icloud.com (small chance though) and the Trash on your Mac?

Comment: Do you have Time Machine backups?